# Python Syntax Highlighting in Microsoft Word

Tags: python, ms-word

Is there any way I can get my Python code syntax highlighted in Microsoft Word?

Comment: Ambiguous. This is programming related

Comment: true, it is kind of 50-50. But python tag removed.

Comment: It's basically same question as http://superuser.com/questions/39571/how-do-i-easily-highlight-the-syntax-of-php-code-in-word

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use a [pastebin](https://gist.github.com/) that does syntax highlighting, for example:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/82cb7f691673e0147edf

Then copy and paste the syntax highlighted code into Word. Worked perfectly for me.

Comment: Here's [another one](http://www.planetb.ca/2008/11/syntax-highlight-code-in-word-documents/) that worked for me if that doesn't work for someone down the road...

Answer (score 2):

Open or copy paste the code in [Google-Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/welcome.ipynb#recent=true) . Copying from colab notebook does syntax highlighting.